# why my file permission being changed after pull from git repository

Tags: git, file-permissions

I have been came across this problem over and over again. I have a git repository set up on my remote server and all the files are set to 644 and folders are set to 755. However, every time after i pulling from git repository(i'm using bitbucket), i noticed the permission of the file which i modified was changed into 664 which results a Internal server Error. For example, I changed the index.php, and it occurs 500 when i tried to get access to it

i have to use 
`find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755` and `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644` to manually changed my files permission back to normal

Comment: Sounds like this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git